# FocusedRowHandle not setting correctly in a DevExpress GridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am trying to update my GridView to auto select a new row that is added after the user fills out the fields and presses add. However, I am having no luck when trying to set the FocusedRowHandle property. The FocusedRowHandle value stays at -2147483648 even after I try to assign a value to it as shown in the following code:

```
private void gvExample_RowUpdated(object sender, RowObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {             
                ExampleMethodToUpdateTableAdapter();

                GridView view = sender as GridView;
                Object obj;
                if (e.RowHandle != GridControl.NewItemRowHandle)
                    obj = view.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
                else
                {
                    dsExample.dtExample.DefaultView.Sort = "ID desc";
                    DataTable dtSorted = dsExample.dtExample.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
                    int lastID = Convert.ToInt32(dtSorted.Rows[0]["ID"]);
                    gvExample.FocusedRowHandle = lastID;
                }             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {              
            }
        }
```

When stepping into the else statement the aim was to get the latest ID from the DataTable now it has been updated (since the value at e.RowHandle is -2147483648 because its a new row) and set the Focused Row to this ID.

I have tried to have a look online for this but can't seem to find a solution so I thought I'd have a go at posting on here. Apologies if I've missed any info out.

Comment: The new row is not a part of the gridview's datasource at this point. Finish adding it first and then you'll have the handle that you need.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič I thought it may be something to do with that but even when I hardcode "gvExample.FocusedRowHandle = 5" which is a row that definitely exists it still doesn't update the value from -2147483648

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct you want to focus the new row (which is the last row):

```
gridView.FocusedRowHandle = gridView.RowCount - 1;
```

If not, you have to search the id inside the gridvw with for i 0-> gridView.RowCount - 1 and then when you will find the Id to focus the row with the i value.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= gridView.RowCount - 1; i++) 
    {
      if (gridView.GetRowCellValue(i, gridView.columns(column_number)))
          {
        gridView.FocusedRowHandle = i;
          }
    }
```